# High number of select queries shown in MySQL databse

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a RDS MySQL database that serves a basic web app for users to log in to an account.

When I spin up a new version of the app, and there a no current users logged in, I get a high level of `SELECT` queries (c.4,500 per hour) when I view the database query statistics via PHPMyAdmin.

1. Could this be caused by PHPMyAdmin (I know it queries the database to display data, but this seems high)?
2. If not, how can I best trace where the queries are coming from?
3. Am I worrying about nothing here? It's a small RDS instance, do 4,500 requests per hour make an impact on performance? Should it be something I need to fix?

Comment: phpMyAdmin DOES use a lot of request. See if you get requests when no one is using phpmyadmin.

Comment: Thanks, how can I view query statistics without phpmyadmin?

Comment: In your amazon aws console I think

Comment: Unfortunately there's no option to show query stats in the AWS console

Answer (score 0):

In phpMyAdmin, use Status > Monitor. Then click on Instructions/setup, you'll get advice about some necessary settings. Then you can select a portion of the generated Questions graph and see which queries where generated during this time frame.